# Resetting form and focusing on the first input field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I have a `redux-form` that I'm using in my React Native project. I'm trying to add some trivial usability enhancements to the form by simply doing the following after a failed submit:

- Reset the input fields so that they're blank
- Focus on the first input field in the form so the user doesn't have to manually click it. In this case it is a username input field.

I have this mostly working. The problem is, after I reset the form and manually have to `focus()` on the username input field, it triggers the touched + error states, thus showing that the password field is required. I thought resetting the form would take care of that would do the trick, but it does not.

After the user submits the form, the following lifecycle event will be called:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if ( nextProps.network.failed_login && this.state.submitted ) {

            this.setState({ submitted: false })

            nextProps.resetLoginForm();

            // this._usernameInput._root.focus();
        }
    }
```

This is what `nextProps.resetLoginForm()` actually looks like:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        resetLoginForm() {
            dispatch(reset("login"))
        },
        loginUser: (username, password) => dispatch(loginUser(username, password))  
    }
}
```

This is what each `Field` calls in its `component` prop:

```
renderInput = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning, value } }) => {
        let textInput = null;

        return (
          <View>
            <Item error={error && touched} style={styles.inputGrp}> 
              <Icon
                active
                name={
                  input.name === "username" ? "person" : "ios-unlock-outline"
                }
                style={{ color: commonColor.contentTextColor }}
              />
              <Input
                ref={c => { textInput = c; if ( input.name === "username" ) this._usernameInput = c; } }
                placeholderTextColor={commonColor.lightTextColor}
                style={{ color: commonColor.contentTextColor }}
                placeholder={input.name === "username" ? "Username" : "Password"}
                secureTextEntry={input.name === "password" ? true : false}
                autoFocus={ input.name === "username" ? true : false }
                {...input}
              />
              {touched && error
                 ? <Icon
                     active
                     style={styles.formErrorIcon}
                     onPress={() => textInput._root.clear()}
                     name="close"
                   />
                 : <Text />}
                {touched && error
                ? <Text style={styles.formErrorText1}>
                    {error}
                  </Text>
                : <Text style={styles.formErrorText2}>error here</Text>}
            </Item>

          </View>
        );
    }
```

and finally the `render` method:

```
render() {
        const { handleSubmit, reset } = this.props;

        const loginError = this.props.network.failed_login ? (
            <Text>Invalid username/password</Text>
        ) : null;

        const submitMarkup = this.state.submitted ? (
            <Spinner color="#663399" />
        ) : (
            <Button
                block
                style={styles.loginBtn}
                onPress={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}
            >
                <Text style={{ lineHeight: 16, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    Login
                </Text>
            </Button>
        )

        return (
            <View>
                <Modal isVisible={this.props.isVisible}>
                    <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.formContainerView}>
                            <View style={styles.formView}>
                                <Field
                                    name="username"
                                    component={this.renderInput}
                                    type="username"
                                    validate={[alphaNumeric, required]}
                                />
                                 <Field
                                    name="password"
                                    component={this.renderInput}
                                    type="password"
                                    validate={[alphaNumeric, required]}
                                />

                                {submitMarkup}

                                {loginError}

                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

`autoFocus` works when the form is initially rendered, but NOT after a submit action.

What's the best way of ensuring that I can clear my form, focus on the first input field, and make sure zero errors are triggered for having an empty input since my validation requires a password input to be non-empty?

Answer (score 1):

*Redux Forms **does not** register the refs, it should be done by the user*

Therefore this is the only way to `focus` the `TextInput`. If your `resetAction` *re-renders the form* then you can use [**autoFocus**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus) in the `TextInput`.

You can make use [**touched**](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/), to show your errors. *By default this will be set when the field is blurred.*

Comment: I do focus. Look at my code example. The problem is, when the form re-renders, it doesn't auto focus on the username field, even though autoFocus is set on it.

Comment: `autoFocus` is set in `ComponentDidMount`, therefore unless your component is not re-rendered it wont trigger

Comment: so what's the right solution to autoFocus after submit?

Comment: As for now it would be `manual focusing`, but you may change how the error appears in your code based on the [props](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/) provided by them

Comment: I do manual focusing, but that triggers touched and because it is blank, errors out.

Comment: Can you post the code for error handling, I'll take a look at it soon.

Comment: Sure, I updated my render input method in the question.  Thanks